# Saving large images in good quality automatically (Matlab)

Tags: image, matlab

I'm saving my images with

```
for 1:30
    file = 'stuff.tif'       % 2269 x 1452 image
    RGBImage = imread(file);
    filename = sprintf('example.tif');
    saveas(gcf,filename)
end
```

However when doing so Matlab **down-sizes** my images and saves the image as a  smaller, "zoomed out" version of itself, which cripples its quality.

**Input**, 'stuff.tif' when zoomed in
[image: Input]

**Output**, 'example.tif' when zoomed in
[image: Output]

How can I save my images automatically in a for loop while retaining their original size and quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend using Oliver Woodford's function [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) from the File Exchange. That should solve your problem. (Now Yair Altman takes care of it).

Comment: Can it run in Matlab 2010b? Because that's developed in Matlab 2014b

Comment: Mhh I could not find that information in the docs. I guess you will have to try it; Yair has taken over the maintenance from Oliver Woodford since January of this year.

Comment: To answer my own qn: it works. But the anti aliasing in "using_hg2.m" kept coming up with errors; had to turn it off with " -a1".

Comment: ??? Error using ==> get
There is no 'GraphicsSmoothing'
property in the 'figure' class.

Error in ==> export_fig>parse_args
at 969
        options.aa_factor = 1 + 2
        * (~(using_hg2(fig) &&
        strcmp(get(ancestor(fig,
        'figure'),
        'GraphicsSmoothing'),
        'on')) | (options.renderer
        == 3));

Error in ==> export_fig at 236
    [fig, options] =
    parse_args(nargout, fig,
    varargin{:});

Comment: `HG2` is a graphics system that is fairly recent.  It would make sense that the script doesn't work because 2010 (I'm quite sure) does not have HG2 graphics embedded within.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng I was away from my computer for the last 6h :)